# Convert Datetime column to show only day in a DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, days

I have a DataFrame as follows

```
ID                                      Frq   LastOrderDate          Delta
39924946-a3b0-420a-ac55-11c499274fd8    10    2019-10-17 18:39:50    05:20:10
a4355b4f-2ec4-4f91-a424-3492ac749dd1    47    2019-10-17 18:12:40    05:47:20
83861ce3-0627-40a6-9ac5-d66428015e22    3     2019-10-17 18:04:34    05:55:26
ba3d51fb-f19f-421c-85ae-ef1ffe7c270c    16    2019-10-17 17:48:09    06:11:51
00141b15-4def-4a33-98ff-dfad74714b53    1     2019-03-01 16:47:24    230 days 07:12:36
```

`Delta` column is the substract of the date of '2019-10-18' .

I want to show this column as day only. I tried to use datetime library and simply use `Delta.days` but it did not work.

Comment: *Did not work* means nothing. Show the code you tried, the expected result and the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
from io import StringIO

s = StringIO("""
ID                                      Frq   LastOrderDate     
39924946-a3b0-420a-ac55-11c499274fd8    10    2019-10-17 18:39:50    
a4355b4f-2ec4-4f91-a424-3492ac749dd1    47    2019-10-17 18:12:40    
83861ce3-0627-40a6-9ac5-d66428015e22    3     2019-10-17 18:04:34    
ba3d51fb-f19f-421c-85ae-ef1ffe7c270c    16    2019-10-17 17:48:09    
00141b15-4def-4a33-98ff-dfad74714b53    1     2019-03-01 16:47:24    
""")

df = pd.read_csv(s, sep="\s+")

df.Frq = pd.to_datetime(df.Frq)

df['Delta'] = df.Frq - pd.to_datetime('2019-10-18')
```

[image: The output]